# Real root of a complex equation.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, roots

I was working on a problem from Gamelin; where I was required to find out zeros of $2z^5+6z^1-1$ , in the unit disk (in $\mathbb C$). I applied **Rouché's** theorem and find out zeros in the unit disk and I got to know that there is only one zero inside it.

Further, I have to show that it has one zero inside $(0,1)$ : Following is my answer and I am not sure about it. please correct me if i am wrong.

- This polynomial have only one zero inside the open unit disk. Therefore the only root that exist in unit disk must be a real one. Because complex roots exist only in pairs.
- Now we have to show that this zero is positive. Is it right if I say that, there is 1 changes in sign of the function's coefficients, so there will be at most 1 positive roots (maybe less). And now put -z on the place of z then all coefficients of the polynomial will turn negative. Therefore there is no negative root. So the only root that we have in the unit disk must be real; so it will lie in $(0,1)$.

Comment: First argument is correct because your polynomial has real coefficients. By the way, this is **Rouché's** theorem

Comment: @Pitt: If you're going to appeal to Descartes's Law of Signs, you might as well use its full strength (although I prefer actually thinking through Rouché's Theorem): Since there is one sign change, there is at most one positive real root; on the other hand, the number of sign changes and the number of positive real roots have the same parity, so there must be exactly one positive real root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $2\cdot 0^5 + 6\cdot 0-1 < 0 < 2\cdot 1^5+6\cdot 1-1$.

Comment: Do you mean that at zero it is below x-axis and at 1 it is above x-axis. Therefore it must cut x-axis somewhere btw $(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. That is true for all (real-valued) continuous functions.

Comment: But this is a complex valued function!

Comment: And we cannot visualize it like we do in the case of real valued functions. Am i right?

Comment: @PittHarmanN-FreshmaN : Indeed it is, but its restriction to $\mathbb R$ is a real-valued function!

Comment: Have you read my suggested method? I want to know where i am wrong.

Comment: I read it. Your method is *not* wrong. I just gave a hint for more direct approach.

Comment: I see, Thank you so much dear njguliyev. have a good day.